# Mockito can not mock Hive box with annotation

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, hive, mockito, flutter-test

I try to do a ***unit test*** with logic which use ***Hive box*** in ***Flutter***

I follow guide of UT test flutter and mockito 
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking 
https://pub.dev/packages/mockito

After run: `flutter run build_runner build`
The mock class is generated

I use mockClass such as: 
[image]

But the code doesnot run well.
The box is not oppened error still appear.
[image]

 
 
***How can I mock Hive box correctly?*** 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code and error messages.  Are you sure that this is the error you get from this code?  The error message indicates that the failure stems from the `SettingController` constructor, but the code you've shown does not seem to construct a `SettingController`.

Comment: Because UT for settingController and my code use Hive box in setting controller.
That's reason why I need mock Hive to test. 
Anything you think, please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: Post code (*not screenshots*) that reproduces the problem.  The code that you've shown does not instantiate a `SettingController`.

Comment: You have some `Mock` objects, but it sounds like you didn't use things (e.g. `LocalDataHelper` to use the `Mock` instances).

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin much. 
Thank to you, I detect that I should pass mockObject to constructor.
When I resolved, I will post detail.